# .txt file is acting weird under readlines()

Tags: text, python-2.7, textedit, readlines

The contents of the file look like this:

```
1/15/13,930,1441.5
1/15/13,1000,1442.75
1/15/13,1030,1444
```

I run:

```
the_txt_file = open('/txt_file')
```

Then I run:

```
the_txt_file_as_a_list =  the_txt_file.readlines()
```

Then I run:

```
print the_txt_file_as_a_list
```

And I get this:

```
['1/15/13,930,1441.5\r1/15/13,1000,1442.75\r1/15/13,1030,1444\r1/']
```

But I was expecting something like:

```
['1/15/13,930,1441.5\n','15/13,1000,1442.75\n','15/13,1030,1444\n']
```

This happens to me pretty frequently, what is going on?

Comment: $ xxd /txt_file see if something wrong with the file

Comment: Seems like the file has carriage returns (\r) but no newlines (\n).

Comment: How would I fix this problem?

Comment: open file using "rU" mode

Comment: So : the_txt_file = open('/txt_file', rU)  
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you, or the original creator of this data file were on a Mac. Seems you are expecting it to be a simple '\n' line ending, but suffer from the originating editors system default line ending (most likely).

An easy fix, is to call `open(...)` with the `rU` option like so:

`the_txt_file = open('/txt_file', 'rU')`

This ensures that the file is opened **r**ead only, and uses **U**niversal newline support when reading the particular file.

Good luck!

Comment: This worked perfectly. I tested it by doing separate two things:
1. print the_txt_file
2. for item in the_txt_file:
    print item

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that the problem had something to do with the way my mac interacted with the .txt file

The problem was fixed by swapping:

```
the_txt_file = open('/txt_file')
```

with:

```
the_txt_file = open('/txt_file', 'rU')
```

The 'rU' is called 'universal-readline'. Opening a file in 'rU' mode is opening a file in Universal readline mode. Upon running:

```
the_txt_file_as_a_list =  the_txt_file.readlines()
```

and then:

```
print the_txt_file_as_a_list
```

my output went from:

```
['1/15/13,930,1441.5\r1/15/13,1000,1442.75\r1/15/13,1030,1444\r1/']
```

to:

```
['1/15/13,930,1441.5\n', '1/15/13,1000,1442.75\n', '1/15/13,1030,1444\n']
```

Later, I was able to print each item seperatly by:

```
for item in the_txt_file_as_a_list:
    print item
```

The output looked like:

```
1/15/13,930,1441.5

1/15/13,1000,1442.75

1/15/13,1030,1444
```